# "propose" without a suggestion

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, verbs

Is "proposes" used properly in the following? The following that-clause is not a suggestion.

> In his book “Mother Tongue: The English Language”, Bill Bryson states that this richness of vocabulary gives English an advantage over many other languages. He **proposes** that a language with a wider vocabulary has more ways to express the same thought.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context of the passage. Usually one proposes something for some form of consideration, in this case perhaps by people who are debating the consequences of having lots of words in a language. One person may put forward one point of view and Bill would propose an alternate point of view. However, if Bill is merely putting forward this idea without such intention—perhaps because there is no debate and no need for the consideration of others—then I'd suggest the correct word is "posit".

Answer (score 1):

One can propose a plan of action, e.g. 'he proposed a new nine-point peace plan', but as with bsod, I would suggest that it is inappropriate without a suggested plan or action.

[Propose (Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/propose)